# Unexpected behavior of WhenEvent in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

In *Mathematica* 9.0.1, here is a simple code to numerically solve an initial-value problem:

```
sol = With[{k = 0.4, x0 = .01, xMax = 20}, 
  ParametricNDSolve[
    {y''[x] + 3/x y'[x] - y[x] + 3/2 y[x]^2 - k/2 y[x]^3 == 0 (*diff. eq.*), 
     y[x0] == y0 + 1/8 x0^2 (y0 - 3/2 y0^2 + k/2 y0^3),       (*init. cond. 1*)
     y'[x0] == 1/4 x0 (y0 - 3/2 y0^2 + k/2 y0^3)              (*init. cond. 2*), 
    WhenEvent[y[x] == 0, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {x, x0, xMax}, y0]
  ]
```

Then I can make a plot of a solution (with `y0`=4.4), and I get:

```
Plot[y[4.4][x] /. sol, {x, .01, 20}, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}]
```

[image]

But if I modify the `WhenEvent` in the code above so that it reads:

`WhenEvent[y'[x] == 0, "StopIntegration"]}, y, {x, x0, xMax}, y0]`,

the solution to the differential equation becomes different:

[image]

I expected `NDSolve` to stop integrating when the curve begins to turn around near `x`=5.  Instead, the whole solution changes -- and it doesn't stop integrating.  Am I misinterpreting `WhenEvent`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are doing, but for me `y[4.4]/.sol` returns an `InterpolatingFunction` which is valid from 0.01 to 5.14 and that seems to be the value where `y'` becomes zero as desired. You can of course still plot it but for values larger than `x=5.14` but then only an extrapolation of that `InterpolatingFunction` is plotted, nothing that has anything to do with the real solution. I'm not sure why they changed the older behaviour where you'd have seen a bunch of warning messages but in any case you should check the end point before plotting when using `"StopIntegration"`...

Comment: **Headslap!**  Yes.. you're right.

Comment: great, I wasn't sure but as I struggled about this myself it was an easy guess :-)

Comment: I have added my comment as an answer, so if you want you can accept it and make that question disappear from the unanswered list...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the output of:

```
y[4.4]/.sol
```

you will find that that is an interpolating function which is valid from `x=0.01` to roughly `5.14`. If one plots that result from `x=0.01` to `5.14` that shows that `5.14` is the point where the derivative becomes zero. So it looks like `NDSolve` does the right thing. What happens when you `Plot` from `x=0.01` to `xMax=20` is that Mathematica uses an extrapolation of the result for values larger than `5.14` in the plot, and of course that extrapolation doesn't have to anything with the real solution for values larger than `5.14`. Older versions of Mathematica would have given some warning messages about having used extrapolations of an interpolating function, but newer don't do that anymore. I'm not sure whether that was a wise design decision as these messages would have helped you to immediately see the problem and in the probably relatively unlikely case you realy wanted to use extrapolations it would be easy enough to switch those messages off.

Anyway, if ever you use a `WhenEvent` with `"StopIntegration"` you better extract the integration end point and use that when making use of the result, e.g. for a plot:

```
With[{xMax = ((y[4.4] /. sol)@"Domain")[[1, 2]]},
  Plot[y[4.4][x] /. sol, {x, .01, xMax}, PlotRange -> {-1, 5}]
]
```

I would also strongly recommend to learn about the new version of `*NDSolveValue` call functions which directly return the interpolating functions, which makes such operations somewhat more convenient:

```
sol = With[{k = 0.4, x0 = .01, xMax = 20}, 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[{
     y''[x] + 3/x y'[x] - y[x] + 3/2 y[x]^2 - k/2 y[x]^3 == 0 (*diff.eq.*), 
     y[x0] == y0 + 1/8 x0^2 (y0 - 3/2 y0^2 + k/2 y0^3),    (*init.cond.1*)
     y'[x0] ==  1/4 x0 (y0 - 3/2 y0^2 + k/2 y0^3)          (*init.cond.2*), 
     WhenEvent[y'[x] == 0, "StopIntegration"]
   }, y, {x, x0, xMax}, y0]
]

 Plot[sol[4.4][x], {x, .01, (sol[4.4]@"Domain")[[1, 2]]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1, 5}]
```